# Cannot Integration Test Thingdom neo4j Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I was struggling to include the the neo4j thingdom module in my unit testing (question: [How can i use sinon to stub functions for neo4j Thingdom module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716793/how-can-i-use-sinon-to-stub-functions-for-neo4j-thingdom-module)) so i decided to abstract it out and create a simple wrapper around the module so i could unit test my modules my mocking/stubbing out the abstraction.

I thought i would still validate that this module was working, not by unit testing or building it out via tests as it really has no clever behavior (it just wraps the standard functions)  bit i would integration test it to ensure it was calling the database and doing what underlying module should be doing.

created a test file, using mocha syntax and the good old command line started creating a few tests and all pass....problem is they pass regardless as for some reason in the context of executing the tests the method call to the thingdom module (and the subsequent calls backs) never get called, nothing gets returned and the tests just pass.

the function looks like:

```
NeoProvider.get = function (id, next) {
    db.getNodeById(id, function (err, node) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        next(null, node);
    });
};
```

the test (the 'aaa' was me trying my hardest to get it to fail:

```
    it('should get a node from the database based on a specific id', function(){
        //var neo = new ();
        NeoProvider.get(id, function(err, node){
            node.should.eql('aaa');
       });
    });
```

Whats odd is if you call the function through the normal context (a server, in this case Resify) the code works, a node is returned (or undefined if it doesn't exist) so it only seems to not give a hoo when you try and run it via the test runner?

Is this quote normal or have i done something incredibly stupid (which would make more sense)

Comment: Hey Modika, I'm the maintainer and co-author of node-neo4j. =) What you're describing shouldn't be the case -- there's no reason I can think of that node-neo4j code would work regularly but not through a test runner (and we in fact test extensively on top of it, though not mocking it out as you're doing). Your sample code also has some minor issues, so that could be it. How about we figure this out via the mailing list? http://groups.google.com/group/node-neo4j

Comment: Hi Aseem, thanks for the comment, i will pop over to the mailing list and we can chat, and if we can find a solution i will update the question.  In the above i a not mocking it, i tried and failed :) the thingdom module is just included in a simple wrapper module which i am trying to integration test, so the above should be called as is.